# PostgreSQL Function with OUT Parameter as JSON

Tags: postgresql

Can I create a function in PostgreSQL DB which returns an Integer and also has a JSON OUT parameter?

I'm facing issue while creating the same.

**Error Message :**
ERROR: function result type must be json because of OUT parameters

```
CREATE FUNCTION pms.func_test(OUT p_json json)
    RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
BEGIN
    SELECT to_json(JSON_BUILD_OBJECT( 'ID', 10 ))
    INTO p_json ;
    
    RETURN( 1 ) ;
END ;
$BODY$;

ALTER FUNCTION pms.func_test()
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Regards
Manoj

Comment: Change the `RETURN( 1 );` to `RETURN;`.

Comment: I got totally confused. I was treating it same way as Oracle has. In oracle RETURN value is different than IN, OUT or INOUT parameters. In Oracle functions RETURN type only tells about value to be returned by RETURN statement. IN, OUT or INOUT parameter are independent of this. Function must have one return type and it can have many IN, OUT or INOUT parameters. In PostgreSQL there is some relation in RETURN type and OUT parameter. Can you please help me understand this.

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING